# page navigation without losing form field data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to know instead of using PHP Sessions to save the field data, is there any concept in Ajax or jQuery, to navigate between lot of form pages, but to save the form data until the user submits, if user submits, all the information present on different pages should also get submitted.

Comment: Work with a single page. Show/hide form sections as necessary. Eventually, ensure all sections are showing before submission, otherwise hidden section won't be submitted.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: You can fetch the value of a form element even if it's hidden. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gn3Xw/.

Comment: @Luka, yes of course you can. Read what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the form wizard its a jquery plugin : http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple concepts of that type.

You can use JavaScript with the jQuery library to paginate a huge form using functions for HTML elements manipulation. That way, you don't require the user to create another HTTP request, and thus the information entered on other pages doesn't get lost when the user switches pages. The form can then be submitted using AJAX or a normal, "front-end" HTTP request method.

Also, you could try saving the entered information in a cookie with JavaScript and jQuery.

Here are some examples of jQuery pagination:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/pajinate/examples/example1.html.

You can easily apply these concepts with anything, including HTML forms.

And here are various plugins with source:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/.

A cookie is nothing more than a plain text file that is stored on a visitor's computer, which means you can easily encode and embed your form data into it.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, can you post an example or demo for this ? Thanks again

Comment: yeah but will this work in the form fields? Will the form fields be saved if we navigate ?

Comment: If you want to save the form fields and navigate to another page using new HTTP requests, you'd have to store that information inside a cookie.

Comment: well, you are right, what I am thinking like, after all the forms are filled by the user, I want to display all the pagination stuff into single page so that every field will be saved into the database after the user clicks on Submit... Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can display all form fields for the user to review everything entered, or you can leave other pages hidden and collect the data using JavaScript while the form is being filled out. Then when the user clicks the "Submit" button, you can easily embed all that form data into the HTTP POST request. Remember that you don't have to display everything in order to have it available.